# Warning for Duplicate Entry pops out even if not duplicate

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, duplicates

I created VBA code in an MS Access entry form to restrict duplicate entry of request number.
It throws the warning when I enter duplicate value. My problem is that, it keeps on throwing warning even if I enter unique one.

```
Private Sub Request_Number_AfterUpdate()

Dim Request_Number As String
Dim Answer As Variant

Answer = DLookup("[Request Number]", "GSAPAssets", "[Request Number] ='" & Me.Request_Number & "'")

If Not IsNull(Answer) Then
    MsgBox "Req Number Already in use.", vbInformation, "Duplicate Details."
    Me.Request_Number = ""
    Cancel = True
    Me.Request_Number.SetFocus

Else:
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Use BeforeUpdate event to validate input and use `Cancel = True`. That expression does nothing in AfterUpdate event. Need to have `Option Explicit` in header of every code module.

Comment: ^^ This, and: [Debugging VBA Code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx). Step through the code and inspect the value of `Answer`.

Comment: I have followed and change it to before update but still encountering the same issue. It is notifying when duplicate but still keeps on notifying even if it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is okay, i tried it and it worked well, for non existent values in gpassets table, it does not show the message box, if you need any other assistance,let me know